# Targeting Glass as well as tablets. Are multiple intent-filters required?

Tags: android, google-glass

My current Android application defines its intent filter as:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In order to extend the application to run on Glass, I understand that I need the following intent filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

If I replace my existing intent-filter with the one for Glass, would my application still work for tablets and other Android devices? Or, should I leave my existing filter as is and add a new filter for Glass? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, my testing shows that you can support Google Glass as well as other Android devices by adding both the intent filters.

Answer (score 1):

Few existing applications (any?!) have the user interface design and presentation required to be good GlassWare. I would recommend that you create a separate application, but share the underlying code as it makes architectural sense.